# excel. how to sum certain criteria per group on new row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a raw data set right now that is set up in columns like so:

```
Group1  Cost 1  Amount
Group1  Cost 2  Amount
Group1  Cost 3  Amount
Group1  Cost 4  Amount
Group2  Cost 1  Amount
Group2  Cost 2  Amount
Group2  Cost 3  Amount
Group2  Cost 4  Amount
Group3  Cost 1  Amount
Group3  Cost 2  Amount
```

I want to (I'm guessing this requires a macro) sum the amounts for costs 2&3 on a new row for each group. The group & cost columns are just titles.Is this possible?

Ignore the first highlighted field.
I kind of tried to show what I wanted to do, with two groups. I need to sum the light blue line items for each group. The groups being the 1111111 column.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2vj3.png

Comment: You might want to look into SUMIF() or SUMPRODUCT() formulas

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in whatever cell you want the sum to be in and do =SUM(Cost2+Cost3).  So for example lets say Group1 Cost2 is in C3 and Group1 Cost3 is in C4 the formula would be `=SUM(C3+C4)`

Comment: I have like a thousand records to do this for and each group doesn't necessarily contain the same number of cost groups. How would i do that for my whole data set?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot sample of your dataset and where you would like the sum to be displayed.  Also, is this data being returned from a database like SQL Server, Access, MSQL or something where you could perform the calculation there then pass it to Excel? --- W/O seeing the data hard to exactly tell how to do such.

Answer (score 0):

use this formula:

=SUMPRODUCT(N(A:A="Group1"),N(B:B="Cost 2"),C:C)+SUMPRODUCT(N(A:A="Group1"),N(B:B="Cost 3"),C:C)

But after entering the formula you should press ctrl-alt-enter not "enter" directly